# Selecting a 30 EOD records from an hourly set in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, time-series, aggregate-functions

I'm a novice mySQL dev and I'm trying to tackle something a little tricky. I have a table full of hourly records that are timestamped on 'created'.

I need to write a query that will pull 30 records from the table where each record is the last record of the day for the 30 days starting from NOW().

I subsequently need to do the same for 24 weeks and 12 months but I assume once I have 1 query ironed out for the days, I can figure out the rest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far, and how the results from that did not meet your requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't hard if you use an appropriate aggregate query.

Assuming your table is `records` and your `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column is called `time_stamp`.

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE(time_stamp) AS the_day,
       MAX(time_stamp) AS eod_timestamp
  FROM records
 WHERE time_stamp >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
 GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp)
```

This gets the latest (MAX) time_stamp for each day in the table for the last 30 days.

If you want to locate the exact rows in `records` that have those end-of-day timestamps, you can join this aggregate query to the `records` table like so.

```
 SELECT eod.the_day, r.whatever, r.whatever, r.whatever
   FROM records AS r
   JOIN (
        SELECT DATE(time_stamp) AS the_day,
              MAX(time_stamp) AS eod_timestamp
         FROM records
        WHERE time_stamp >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
        GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp)
        ) AS eod ON r.time_stamp = eod.eod_timestamp
```

Notice that the `ON` clause in the query pulls out the rows from `records` that have the end-of-day timestamps.  If more than one record has the same end-of-day timestamp, this query will get them all.

Comment: Thanks Ollie! Worked like a charm. I was able to easily adapt this for what I was trying to do as well as a few other things. The whole subquery joins are kinda foreign to me.

Comment: This business of a subqery (or virtual table) being joined to each other is the heart of STRUCTURED query language.

Comment: I guess I should rephrase that, subqueries utilizing timestamps.. I've done inner/outer joins for years for mostly page data. Haven't done much metric related stuff in SQL but I was tired of using my scripts to so the heavy lifting.